# Why doesn't this setTimeout fire at all?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I'm using Knockout js and I must be missing something here that is very conceptual. I'm not getting an error so it's hard for me to understand where I am going wrong. I simply want to pull data every X seconds and repopulate my table with that data. I'm using Knockout js for bindings. This sample code should be suffice to display the issue:

```
            function AppViewModel() {
            var self = this;
            self.servers = ko.observableArray([{ Name: 'Loading...', Url: 'Loading...', Environment: 'Loading...', Health: 'Loading...' }]);
            self.refreshServers = function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetData", "Temp")',
                    data: { id: 1 },
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function (data) {
                        self.servers(data);
                        console.log("finished loading data");
                    }
                });
            };
            self.refreshServers();
            setInterval(self.refreshServers, 15000);
        }
        ko.applyBindings(fViewModel);
```

I call the function self.refreshServers once directly to immediately populate the data (maybe there is a better way to do this?) and then I set the timeout to continuously call. I never see a second ajax request nor a second log function come through.

Comment: Your first self.refreshServers call doesn't have any invocation - should be self.refreshServers() - those parens gotta be there

Comment: Oddly it still calls the function once. I initially had self.refreshServers = new function so I think that's why I didn't have the parens at one point.

Comment: it calls it once because of the setTimeout call

Comment: @Tada it calls it after 15 seconds but you need to move your setTimeout to inside of the function if you want it to loop, or use setInterval

Comment: @PW Kad are you sure? I thougth the point of setTimeout was that it would call the specified function continuously...Not that I need to setTimeout inside the function itself...

Comment: setTimeout = once, setInterval = untill canceled.

Comment: You're thinking of setInterval if you want it to keep calling the function on an interval

Comment: Even after changing it to setInterval there is still only one call happening....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues here actually.

The first is that based on your description of the issue, it sounds like you might want 'setInterval()' and not 'setTimeout()'. The difference is that 'setInterval()' will continuously execute based on a certain interval of time, whereas 'setTimeout()' will only execute once after the time has elapsed.

The second issue is that, as others have mentioned, is that the first call to 'self.refreshServers()' does need the parenthesis in order to execute the first call, and the reference inside 'setInterval()' should not have parenthesis. This is because in 'setInterval()', you are passing a reference to a function that will be executed, not the result of an executed function.

Minus the AJAX, here is a working example based on your code:

```
function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.numberOfIntervals = 0;

    self.servers = ko.observableArray([{
        Name: 'Loading...',
        Url: 'Loading...',
        Environment: 'Loading...',
        Health: 'Loading...'
    }]);

    self.refreshServers = function () {
        // AJAX GOES HERE... THEN UPDATE RESULTS
        self.servers.push({
            Name: 'New Name...' + self.numberOfIntervals,
            Url: 'New Url...' + self.numberOfIntervals,
            Environment: 'New Enviornment...' + self.numberOfIntervals,
            Health: 'New Health...' + self.numberOfIntervals
        });

        self.numberOfIntervals++;
    };

    self.refreshServers();
    setInterval(self.refreshServers, 3000);
}

ko.applyBindings(AppViewModel);
```

Here is a working fiddle to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/dunka494/4/

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Functions are end with `()` so in this case your function might be called `refreshServers()`. Notice also that you set the timer on 15 seconds, which IMHO is quiet long.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Currently the operation to fetch the data is a bit long running, so 15 seconds is ok in my case. I will revisit this at a later time though.

Comment: You could also run the action when the ajax call is finished. Place the code in between `success: function (data) {
                        self.refreshServers();
                    }`

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout(self.refreshServers, 15000);` is running immediately when `AppViewModel()` is invoked.

as you stated, it runs immediately, because it needs `function(){}` as a parameter to actually be executed after the desired 15 seconds.

try this instead:

```
....
setTimeout(function(){
    self.refreshServers();
}, 15000);
.....
```

**
be careful here; `setInterval` is not the same as `setTimeout`.

`setInterval` will run a piece or block of code periodically in a given interval, while `setTimeout` will run it only once (or rather each time `AppViewModel()` is invoked). as you stated, your code runs once, but probably way before you actually want it to run.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @kinakuta and @Marin Smit for pointing out the obvious that I failed to understand. I apparently read the difference between setInterval and setTimeout entirely too quickly.

The two solutions were adding parenthesis and changing from setTimeout to setInterval